# Lightbox2 does not work

Tags: lightbox2

I am running Lightbox v2.03.3 in a standard html document. Actually, the file has a .php extension, but only because I am using php includes. Anyway, most of the images on this page are setup to use lightbox to display them.

I verified that the lightbox files are uploaded, called from the correct folder, and working. Every image that is being called is actually there.

I have the following code in the HEAD section of my web page.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Scripts/LightBox/css/lightbox.css"
type="text/css" media="screen" /> <script type="text/javascript"
src="/Scripts/LightBox/js/prototype.js"></script> <script
type="text/javascript"
src="/Scripts/LightBox/js/scriptaculous.js?load=effects"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="/Scripts/LightBox/js/lightbox.js"></script>

<script>
    lightbox.option({
      'resizeDuration': 200,
      'wrapAround': true
    }) </script>
```

and this code is attached to each most of the images on the page.

```
<a href="images/SilverSpur2015/EarlHolliman.jpg"
rel="lightbox[closeup]" title="Earl Holliman">
```

The problem is that when I click on an image, it just shows the picture as if I did not have any lightbox commands in the code.

You can see the actual page at http://www.reelcowboys.org/index_new.php

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the data-lightbox attribute to the element.

```
<a href="images/SilverSpur2015/EarlHolliman.jpg" data-lightbox="insert-set-name-here" rel="lightbox[closeup]" title="Earl Holliman">
```